# ASP.NET MVC 5 won't recognize primary key

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, entity

I have an issue with my code-first model's primary key.

Here is what my model class looks like:

```
public class Expense
{
    public int ExpenseId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public float Amount { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to create an instance of this class like:

```
Expense MyExpense = new Expense();
MyExpense.Description = "Some Expenses";
MyExpense.Amount = 1234;

MyDbContext.Expenses.Add(MyExpense);
MyDbContext.SaveChanges();
```

I get the following error

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ExpenseId', table 'aspnet-SomeDB-20161219050403.dbo.Expenses'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Here is what my migration file looks like (I've removed a few things from model to keep it simple).

```
CreateTable("dbo.Expenses",
            c => new
                 {
                     ExpenseId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                     Description = c.String(),
                     Amount = c.Single(nullable: false),
                     PaymetnDate = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                     AddedById = c.String(maxLength: 128),
                  })
             .PrimaryKey(t => t.ExpenseId)
             .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.AddedById)
             .Index(t => t.AddedById);
```

Comment: Seems pretty clear that primary key don't accept nulls and you didn't set any value for it

Comment: You've not defined anywhere what kind of values this column should contain. Just because it's the **primary key** doesn't mean that SQL Server is going to automatically generate values for it - what you're missing is the notion that this is an **identity** column

Comment: Side note: I would **never** use `float` as a datatype for something called `Amount` - if you need precise math, you should use `decimal` instead `float` is *notorious* for being imprecise and showing rounding errors etc

Answer (score 0):

Just decorate the ExpenseId field on your Expense class as below and SQL Server will automatically generate the value on insert.

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
[Key]
public int ExpenseId { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the table designer you can set the id column to automatically iterate - in the properties window

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your primary key is a string and EntityFramework does not know how to auto-increment it! The other answers were correct, however, EntityFramework should automatically set the ExpenseId as auto-incrementing and as a primary key for you. However, it did not because look closely at your migration code:

```
CreateTable("dbo.Expenses",
            c => new
                 {
                     ExpenseId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128), //<------ ExpenseId is a string!!!
                     Description = c.String(),
                     Amount = c.Single(nullable: false),
                     PaymetnDate = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                     AddedById = c.String(maxLength: 128),
                  })
             .PrimaryKey(t => t.ExpenseId)
             .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.AddedById)
             .Index(t => t.AddedById);
```

Another thing to note is that `PaymentDate` is mis-spelled as `PaymetnDate` . Did you change the ExpenseId's data type after you built the migration? If you re-build the migration or otherwise fix the code so that it inserts an int ExpensideId instead of a string, you'll be good to go. This is the way it should be anyway because that is how you specified it to be in your model.

If you actually intended the ExpenseId to be a string, then you need to update your question or comment about that and I can update the answer accordingly, but just know that Entity Framework does not know how to "increment" a string as it is not necessarily a number.